# Are Den Den Mushis conscious?

Tags: one-piece

In One Piece there are some [snail-like creatures](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Den_Den_Mushi) that

> ..have the ability to communicate with each other telepathically through
>   radio waves. The people in One Piece world take advantage of this
>   ability by attaching buttons and receivers to them. Den Den Mushi thus
>   take the place of telephones and other similar machines in the world
>   of One Piece.

[image]

I have never seen one moving about freely. Are they *fully* conscious of their surroundings, could they move freely if they wanted to? Or do once they become tamed and personalized they just become fully fledged telephones?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only one sort of moving Den Den Mushi.
The only place where you see then is in the [Tenth movie](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/One_Piece_Film:_Strong_World)

> **Self-Propelled Visual Den Den Mushi**
> Shiki has a variant of the Visual Den Den Mushi called the
> Self-Propelled Visual Den Den Mushi (自走式映像転送電伝虫 Jisō-shiki Eizō Tensō
> Den-den Mushi?). As the name implies they are able to move and look
> around. They also appear to be close to the same size as the larger
> variant of the Visual Den Den Mushi and have attachments that allow
> them to project what they can see to a monitor.

The Den Den mushi are normal snails untill people attach the phones to them.

This is taken from [SBS 41](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/SBS_Volume_41)(Q&A with author)

> **D:** In Chapter 367, Sanji-kun destroys the Den Den Mushi. That's so
> mean!!! The Den Den Mushi didn't do anything wrong! Even a Den Den
> Mushi would cry if that happened to it! It cries when it hurts! It
> cries because its heart hurts even more than its body! So let's
> apologize to it, shall we? P.N. Naoko
>
> **O:** Oh, well, you see... OK, I
> admit, I may have created that impression, but it's okay. On the right
> is a wild Den Den Mushi. It has the ability to communicate with its
> species through radio (thought) waves. Humans attach buttons and
> receivers to them so they can contact specific other Den Den Mushi.
> So, you can destroy the receiver without hurting the Den Den Mushi.

[image]